# How to know whether MKMapView visibleMapRect contains a Coordinate?

Tags: ios, ios5, mkmapview, mapkit

If I have a MKMapView and a CLLocationCoordinate2D how do you test whether the map's visible area contains the coordinate?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The fastest way is to use the inbuilt Apple functions which will make this sort of thing super quick!

```
if(MKMapRectContainsPoint(mapView.visibleMapRect, MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate)))
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Where coordinate is your CLLocation2D.

This will be much faster than working out coordinates with a bulk if statement.  Reason is that Apple use a Quadtree and can do fast lookups for you.

Answer (score 6):

## Swift 3 compatible

If you frequently work with maps I suggest you to create an extension like this:

```
extension MKMapView {
    
    func contains(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Bool {
        return MKMapRectContainsPoint(self.visibleMapRect, MKMapPointForCoordinate(coordinate))
    }
    
}
```

Then you can use wherever, for example:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    if mapView.contains(coordinate: mapView.centerCoordinate) {
       // do stuff
    }
}
```

In this way you keep the code:

- more  maintainable: if Apple decide to change its frameworks you will able to do a fast refactor changing code in a single point
- more testable
- more readable and clean

Answer (score 1):

my two cents for swift 5.1

```
  extension MKMapView {

      func contains(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Bool {
        return self.visibleMapRect.contains(MKMapPoint(coordinate))
    }

 }
```