# How to add and remove pins in mapview when zoom in and zoom out

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mapkit, mkmapviewdelegate

I want to update pins on map view when we zoom in and zoom out.For Example I have multiple location on map view now now when I zoom in any one of them So the radius is updated and now those place which are still in radius will remain visible others are remove which are out of the radius.
Any kind of help would be appreciate able.....

Comment: @RoshanSinghBisht Okay let me try

Comment: Hint: You can use `MKMapRectContainsPoint `. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16239443/how-to-know-whether-mkmapview-visiblemaprect-contains-a-coordinate